# C++ Overload resolution ambiguous - GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, standards, overload-resolution

I'm trying to understand, why GCC chooses `f(char, A<C, 5> &var)` for overload-resolution in the code below:

```
template <class C, int N> struct A { };
template <class C> struct A<C, 8> { static_assert(sizeof(C) > 8, "Assertion in A<C,8>"); };
template <class C> struct A<C, 5> { static_assert(sizeof(C) < 8, "Assertion in A<C,5>"); operator A<C,8>&(); };

template <class C> void f(double, A<C,8> &var);
template <class C> void f(char, A<C,5> &var);

int main(void)
{
    A<int, 5> a;
    f(4., a);
}
```

There are two overloads available:

```
template <class C> void f(double, A<C,8> &var);
```

`4.` exact matches `double` (no implicit conversion required), but user defined conversion required for second parameter. So this overload: `exact match` & `user-define conversion`

Next overload, which is matched by GCC:

```
template <class C> void f(char, A<C,5> &var);
```

`4.` requires implicit conversion to `char` but exact match for `A<C,5>`. Is there any reason why GCC choose this overload over previous one?

Can someone find an evidence from section 13 of standard about this particular case? Any help or comment is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deduction cannot succeed for

```
template <class C> void f(double, A<C,8> &var);
```

and an argument of type `A<int, 5>`. I.e. there's no possible type `C` that could make `A<C,8>` match the argument type `A<int,5>`. That a conversion is possible doesn't care for deduction.

See [temp.deduct.call]/4. As conversions can be allowed through converting constructors as well as conversion functions, it isn't possible to consider (all) conversions for type deduction. It could also lead to ambiguities.

Comment: You can see that by removing the second overload. clang++ output: *candidate template ignored: could not match 8 against 5*

Comment: you are right, gcc also errors when the second overload is commented out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So clang and gcc do not care about user-defined conversion. That is `operator A<C,8>&();`?

Comment: @User Well type deduction does not take into account possible conversions, `operator A<C,8>& ()` is one such conversion that isn't taken into account for type deduction. If you explicitly pass the template arguments (generally not recommended), you'll get the ambiguity as expected: `f<int>(4., a);` is ambiguous